# Do aliens killed by car count as kills?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

A soldier fires rocket or throws a grenade not directly at aliens, but at car they are using for cover. Will it still count towards this soldier's kills?

Comment: Good question. I assumed they counted, but I never actually checked... now you've got me wondering!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm almost certain that they do. One of my soldiers just got promoted for a kill made by an exploding car that she put on fire by missing. If they get XP for the kill, it stands to reason that they also get the credit.

Comment: I'd think it's the reverse, actually. They get credit for the kill, so they get XP.

Answer (score -6):

You don't get kills for:

- grenades
- rocket attacks
- exploding cars
- debris falling on aliens
- aliens catching on fire or poisoning themselves.